# Exchange 2003 and Outlook rule: Send auto reply message not working

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook-2007, auto-reply

I have created a distributed group which have to send a auto reply when receiving a mail. I know that it is impossible to send a auto reply within a distributed group, but following a guide I have created a mail account called “noreply”.

In outlook I have created a rule in the “noreply” account where I chose following conditions:

**Send to a person or distributed list (where I selected my distributed group)**

Then to specify what to do with that message I selected

**Have server reply using a specific message**

I’ve created my message and saved it.

But when I try to write an e-mail to the distributed group it doesn’t send back the reply message.

Does anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?

Sincerely
Mestika

Comment: does it work internally or just not at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your intention is to have the noreply account forward your email to the distribution group and respond with an affirmative.

If this is the case, you should send the email to the noreply account, not directly to the distribution group.

Comment: Hi Torai, thanks for your answer. It’s not entirely correct understood. I have a group called “application@company.com”. When someone sends a mail to this group I want to send an automatic reply to the user with some sort of message, that their application has been received. But I can’t do that from a group. So I created the user/mail called “noreply@company.com”. Now, I’ve tried to set – from outlook – a server reply from noreply@company.com, but it doesn’t send anything.

Comment: Hi again Torai. I solved the problem by removing my group and just created a mail called application@company.com where I first created a rule to auto reply a message and then a rule to redirect the mail to the wanted users. Works perfect this way, however not as "pretty". Thanks again for your reply.